# How can an xml string containing an embedded CDATA xml string be formatted as 'pretty' xml

Tags: java, reactjs, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml string containing an  embedded CDATA xml string. I need to format 'pretty' xml

Example string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding-\"UTF-8\" standlaone=\"no\"?>
<catalog>
    <book id=\"b1\">    
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
        <data>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\"  encoding-\"UTF-8\" standlaone=\"no\"?><details><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price><publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date></details>]]>
       </data>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

What is the easiest way in java or reactjs to create a pretty string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding-\"UTF-8\" standlaone=\"no\"?>
<catalog>
    <book id=\"b1\">    
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
        <data>
            <?xml version=\"1.0\"  encoding-\"UTF-8\" standlaone=\"no\"?>
            <details>
                <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
                <genre>Computer</genre>
                <price>44.95</price>
                <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
            </details>
        </data>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

I feel this cannot be done in reactjs and I would need to use java to extract the inner xml and create 2 xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding-\"UTF-8\" standlaone=\"no\"?>
<catalog>
    <book id=\"b1\">    
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding-\"UTF-8\" standlaone=\"yes\"?>
<data>
    <details>
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    </details>
</data>
```

I would appreciate any ideas or alternatives using reactjs or java?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the XML parser doesn't know that the CDATA section contains XML (CDATA means "character data", that is it's explicitly telling the parser to treat the content as plain text, not as markup). So the only way to handle this is to put it through two stages of parsing: the second stage reads the text node representing the CDATA section, and parses it again, grafting the resulting node tree into the original tree.

Note that the output you want isn't well-formed XML: you can't have an XML declaration in the middle of the document. With that qualification, you can achieve the desired effect in XSLT 3.0 as:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

which you can run from Java with the help of the Saxon library. (Disclaimer: my company's product.) The free open-source version will do the job.